# Giving a recommendation for someone I only know by association

Tags: hiring-process, helping

**Scenario**

My friend's significant other is moving to town, and is looking for employment in the same field as me. He's applied for a bunch of different jobs, including my place of employment, and I mentioned that I might be able to help out. No guarantees of course.

I would like to help him get this job, but I'm unsure of how to word it when recommending someone you don't know personally. I understand that it maybe sounds naive, but I'd be doing this as a favor to my friend, and her significant other by association.

**Previous experience**

I've given a couple recommendations before (resulting in permanent employment), but that was for people I went to school with, and I could attest to their character, integrity and to some degree, skill.

I obviously don't intend to lie to HR, saying how good this guy is, when I really don't know, but I'd like to help out in whatever way I can.

**Question**

Is there an acceptable way of recommending someone you don't know very well?

**Caveats**

- the company hires continuously, and will accept any number of good candidates (I feel this is important because his employment wouldn't hinder anyone else's)
- (I repeat) I do not intend to lie to HR by any means - which is why I need advice

**EDIT: Disputing close votes**

The other question is indeed related, but I'm not asking how well I need to know someone to recommend them. This question is about how to word it, if I do decide to do it.

Comment: "Here's a guy I know who does what you're hiring for.  You should interview him and see if he's a fit here."

Comment: Just be honest. Say something like "Not like i know this person since Birth, but my impression is that he/she will be a good asset to the team and it be worthwhile if you could interview"

Comment: @Lilienthal  different animal.  Referring someone to your company is far FAR different from recommending someone.

Comment: @RichardU Check the body of the post and the answers, the difference is asked about and explained in the answers. This question doesn't differ substantially.

Comment: The original question is still on hold, so I'm not sure that closing this because it is a duplicate is appropriate: one of the questions should be good enough to be open, or both should simply be closed.  This might be the better question, but the other appears to me to have better answers.

Comment: Oh fer cryin' out loud!

Comment: Alec, regarding your dispute of the close votes: asking for how to word this is a non-starter since this isn't something you should be doing, as explained in the linked question. The answer to "*Is there an acceptable way of recommending someone you don't know very well?*" would simply be a no.

Comment: @Lilienthal I haven't decided if this is a duplicate or not, but I disagree with your statement that asking for wording is a non-starter. The answer is really how to word a *referral*, not a recommendation. Don't vote to close just because of semantics.

Comment: @DavidK OP disagrees with your interpretation and is explicitly asking about a recommendation: "*I'm not asking how well I need to know someone to recommend them. This question is about how to word it, if I do decide to do it.*"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not know this person well, do not know whether they match the job requirements or their skills and experience, then you cannot "recommend" them for the job as such- you simply *don't know* whether they would be any good. Or to be more accurate, you *can* make such a recommendation but it would not be based on actual knowledge so would be somewhat false.

However you *can* recommend them for interviewing and that doesn't involve you giving your name to a recommendation for them as a worthy employee. When I do this I obtain their CV and pass it to the hiring manager with some wording along the lines of "Might be worth interviewing this person for the [such and such] job?" - This absolves you from any responsibility about deciding if they are any good *and* it means you can go back to your friends and say that you passed their CV on to the right person for the job. Win-win!

Comment: Thanks, that seems like the way to go. He had already applied through normal channels, but I gave HR a call, and suggested that they at least give him the chance to interview.

Answer (score 0):

Recommending someone is a gamble. Specifically, you are staking a portion of your reputation on that person's competence and future success, if they do well, then your opinion will be more respected, if they end up being more trouble than they're worth, then your reputation will suffer similarly.

My advice would be to be honest, saying something along the lines of "I know this person, and they are good at XXX", where XXX is any skill (work related or not) that you are aware they are good at.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot personally comment on either his work or his character you cannot recommend him to HR without either putting your reputation on the line, and facing consequences if he doesn't work out, or actually damaging his chances of getting hired by literally having nothing good to say about him.  HR may consider the latter to be "Damning with faint praise".

You can refer him to the company, you can give him tips on how to navigate, but to mention anything internally will either do you no good, or do him no good.

Answer (score -2):

> Is there an acceptable way of recommending someone you don't know very well?

Yes, just say you don't know them very well.

Comment: Did you miss the word "recommendation"? I mean, your answer would be fine if my question was "how do I inform HR that I don't know this person?"

Comment: probably because you don't know them well enough to be sticking your neck out for them?

Comment: Tell me, if I ask HR to at least let him interview, how is that "sticking my neck out"? No one's gonna blame me for his interviewing skill.

Comment: you're proactively associating yourself with him...is that difficult to understand? Ask them to interview him by all means, but add that you don't know him well. Harmless in all ways. Otherwise it's an implied endorsement of his skills.

Comment: Right, now if that was your point to begin with, do you see how your answer differs in quality from that of Marv Mills, who made the same point?

Comment: I prefer short and sweet, and just assume common sense to fill in rather than write an essay. :-)

Comment: Two paragraphs qualify as an essay where you're from? Easy life... :)